# How to use navigation component with a parent fragment?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have an app, which is a single-activity app. I use dagger2 for di, and an abstraction for navigation.
Let's see a navigation flow: auth - select-info (A, B) - menu. As you can see, there are three main destinations, and the second one contains two screens. I want to make "select-info" as a parent fragment for A and B, but the way navigation component works, I cannot implement that behavior.
I tried to google it, but something close to this issue is an approach to use fragmenManager to go to parentFragment and internally use navComponent, but this approach does not work in my case, because somehow I need to change a navGraph.

As an alternative I see using viewPager in "select-info".

Comment: What do you mean 'the second one contains two screens'? Do you mean the 'select-info' is a fragment that shows both fragment A and fragment B simultaneously on the screen? Or that you first are on fragment A, then fragment B, one at a time, but you need some shared state that covers both fragment A and B?

Comment: @ianhanniballake The second one is a parent fragment, and the start destination is A, and we can navigate from to B. THe parent fragment shows only one screen at a time.

Comment: So why aren't A and B just part of the navigation graph? What is the 'parent fragment' actually needed for?

Comment: @ianhanniballake it is needed for scoping some components to this "select-info" flow, e.g. some dagger dependency.

Comment: If somebody bumped to this problem, I've found a solution and forked an example: https://github.com/Grigoriym/NestedNavFragmentsTest